# How do i add multiple classes to the_post_pagination array?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

If i try to add multiple classes into the the_post_pagination array class string with a space between the words it will stick them together when the code is executed. Is there a way to do this correctly?

```
    <?php
        the_posts_pagination( array( 
            'mid_size'  => 3,
            'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
            'next_text' => '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>' ,
            'prev_text' => '<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>' ,
            'class' => 'pagination justify-content-center',
            ) );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Wordpress sanitizes the class that is included in a pagination, removing certain characters, space included. You can make a hack to overwrite it.

in functions.php, add the following line:

```
add_filter('sanitize_html_class', 'customOverwriteClass', 3, 20);
function customOverwriteClass($sanitized, $class, $fallback) {
    if ( $class === 'your classes'){
        return htmlspecialchars( $class );
    } 
    return $sanitized;
}
```

That way, you will retain the string you need and also clean the input from malicious content. Of course change 'your classes' to the classes you put in the the_post_pagination function.